# Kentico roles and ui personalization

Tags: kentico

I need to give permissions to edit/create/destroy pages in a node to a group of users.

I've created a group and added a test user to that group.

I can't seem to give permission to the Pages application so see if i can see the node.

I also added game this role permissions at the node level too.

Ideally this editor role would be able to create new sub pages, which also means being able to upload media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new user must have *editor* privilege level (you can edit user in *Users* application). If you want to provide ability to see content in *Pages* app you have to grant the user with **Browse tree** and **Read** permission (*content module*). To satisfy your scenario you need to grand user with **Modify** and **Create** permissions, too (maybe **Design**?).

Just FYI: The approach provided by Brenden (cloning the role) is very handy but there a is chance you grant the user with permission you don`t want to provide (inappropriate permissions for original role).

Comment: Thanks martin. I've got it working as i expect. I've got a clearer understanding on setting this up. Next step is to bring AD roles into the mix :)

Comment: Which is why I stated find the one closest to your needs and add/remove abilities.  Setting up a valuable user role from scratch can take hours to perfect for someone who has never used them before.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the most efficient method is review the out of the box roles provided by Kentico and clone the one which fits closest to your needs.  Then modify your cloned role to add/remove abilities and permissions.

If you're unsure of what each role can and cannot do, create a new test user with one of the roles assigned to them and log in as them.  Do the same for all the roles you want to test until you find the one closest to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, never thought of doing it that way. Cheers!

Comment: i cloned the CMS Editor role, then made tweaks from there. Cheers!